how to run two async await task and proceed if both of them completed in flutter
i am displaying splash screen which waits for 3 seconds and then routes to another screen, but my another screen needs GIF files to load, so i have used precaceh method, so my problem is my splash screen awaits for 3 seconds and then awaits for caching image. i want both to run at the same time and run next line (route) only if both of them is finished (i.e. minimum wait time is 3 seconds, and if images takes more time to caching it should increase wait time).
this is my function which is called in init state
 void delayAndRoute() async {
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 3000));
      await precacheImage(AssetImage("assets/images/01.gif"), context);
      await precacheImage(AssetImage("assets/images/02.gif"), context);
      await precacheImage(AssetImage("assets/images/03.gif"), context);

      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const Login(),
        ),
      );
    }


check Future.wait method

Does this answer your question? How do i pass more than one values using Navigator.pop() method in flutter?

no this doesn't answer my question.

Also look at the new Record.wait to enable (future1,future2).wait.

Fully working code
 void delayAndRoute() async {
          // List of futures representing precaching tasks
          List<Future<void>> precacheFutures = [
            Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 3000)),
            precacheImage(AssetImage("assets/images/01.gif"), context),
            precacheImage(AssetImage("assets/images/02.gif"), context),
            precacheImage(AssetImage("assets/images/03.gif"), context),
          ];

      // Waiting for all precaching tasks to complete using Future.wait
      await Future.wait(precacheFutures);

      // Navigating to the next screen after all images are precached
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const Login(),
        ),
      );
    }


you can Future.wait method which takes list of futures and Waits for multiple futures to complete and collects their results.
here is the code:
 Future.wait([
      Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 3000)),
      precacheImage(const AssetImage("assets/images/01.gif"), context),
      precacheImage(const AssetImage("assets/images/02.gif"), context),
      precacheImage(const AssetImage("assets/images/03.gif"), context),
    ]).then(
      (value) {
         Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const Login(),
        ),
      );
      },
    );

